# 25 second delay between TCP connection and HTTP Connect through new proxy

Tags: networking, proxy

I have an application server which makes calls to an external service through the corporate proxy, and it has been running perfectly fine for some time. We are in the process of switching to a new proxy, where we have been facing issues.

After switching the proxy configuration from the old proxy to the new proxy, there is a delay of ~25 seconds between the TCP ACK from the remote, and the client HTTP CONNECT:

[PCAP on new proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ5In.png)

There has been no change in the application code, and the new proxy is not significantly different to the old one. We are changing the proxy so it uses our system proxy, separate to our user proxy for standard internet traffic.

I don't even know where to start looking from here. The proxy logs point to the application being at fault, but there has been no changes and the same version of the code works perfectly fine on the old proxy, which would indicate some issue with the new proxy. Any ideas where to go from here?

In case it's relevant, the application is a .Net Core application running on a Linux Tanzu container.

---

**Update:**
It was the client being silly. I posted a more specific question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1811162/1848800) which has the answer.

Comment: @JaromandaX The property that's set in the [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webproxy?view=net-6.0) is literally just `Proxy`. I don't know the specific implementation details of our corporate proxy server, from my understanding the 'old' and 'new' proxies are two separate instances of the same thing.

Comment: The differences between the proxy instances are things like access control to the server, whitelisted urls/ips, that kind of stuff. Nothing that would have this kind of impact. I'm posting here _after_ already talking to our network team, they have no idea what could be the cause.

Comment: well, then ask them what was before used and afterwards. since your question is currently off topic due it does not meet the [ask] requirements. Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. please share the common thinks like logs etc

Comment: `Any ideas where to go from here?` Given that the delay is on the client, I would investigate what the client is doing in the 25 seconds after the ack received from the remote, and before the application responds. This should be a cautionary tale for anyone implementing similar technologies in such a fashion that makes issue investigation, data collection, and symptom isolation difficult. Let's talk about all the toolkits and debugging and verbose logging capability built in to the kit.

Comment: Also a standard step in a scenario such as this is to perform a correlated packet capture. Having a capture from only one side or endpoint is not adequate, and a blinking red light on a red flag that basic mechanisms are not in place or available to perform data collection at multiple points along the data flows to support an analysis.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me as a problem between the remote server(which using the phone client software) and your new proxy. Not between your App Server and the new proxy. I would compare two tracroutes between the proxy and a specific remote server. One for old proxy and another for new proxy. Then you will find where the actual HTTP delay occurs and maybe notice it's not a HTTP issue but a RTT(Round Trip Time) issue.

Cool!